# Spring dynamic HttpStatus from a variable

Tags: java, spring, spring-web

I have an application where I am returning dynamic HttpStatus code from my controller by using `ResponseEntity`

```
return new ResponseEntity<String>("Unrecognised request.", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
```

The next requirement is that the response body and the status code will be loaded from database. and the code will looking something like

```
String msg = <<loaded from database>>;
String status = <<loaded from database>>; //type can be changed to int
return new ResponseEntity<String>(msg, <..what to do here ??..>);
```

Not the status code will be retrived from database as a string/integer. And as HttpStatus is an Enum, I didn't find any other way to do that.

Is there any solution to my requirement?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If the status code retrieved from the database is always defined as an integer/long/numeric value, you can do similar to this:

```
HttpStatus.valueOf(myCoolStatusCode)
```

Example:

```
int someStatusFromDatabase = databaseService.getMeMyStatus();
String myAwsomeMessage = databaseService.getMeMyStausMessage();
return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.valueOf(someStatusFromDatabase)).body(myAwsomeMessage);
```

Hope this helps!